# autohotkey: add consecutive range of numbers

Tags: math, range, autohotkey, addition

I'm trying to add a range of consecutive odd numbers (13-1001) in Autohotkey.

Is there a formula that will encompass this problem?

This is what I have:

```
a:=13
b:=1001
s1:=((b+1)/2)**2
s2:=((a-1)/2)**2
s:=s1-s2
S3:=z+s
Msgbox,
(   
Step 6 Results:
Z is %z%
First # is %a%
Last # is %b%
Sum of consecutive odd numbers (13-1001) is %s%
Z+Sum is %s3%
```

Comment: Where did `z` come from and what does that formula have to do with Autohotkey?

Comment: I'm answering a series of questions to help me learn more about Autohotkey. The original question is: "Add all odd numbers from 13-1001 (inclusive) to Z" Z was from a previous question. Z=3

Comment: What problems have you encountered while working on your example? How does the shown code relate to the problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: I wanted to make this code more concise and was wondering if there is another function that could do this in less lines.

I was trying the expression below but it doesn't work in Autohotkey:
       add(range(13,1001,2))

Answer (score 0):

## Forward

This logic assumes the following:

- `Start` is less than `End`
- Both `Start` and `End` are odd numbers

## Raw Example

```
Start := 13
, End := 1001

, SumOfOddNumbers := (((End + 1)^2)/4) - ((Start - 1)^2)/4)) 

MsgBox, % "Sum of all odd numbers from " . Start . " to " . End . " is " . SumOfOddNumbers
```

**Output**

```
Sum of all odd numbers from 13 to 1001 is 250965
```

---

## As a function

```
funSumOfOddNumbers( Start, End) {
    Temp := (((End + 1)^2)/4) - ((Start - 1)^2)/4)) 
    return, % Temp
    } ; end function funSumOfOddNumbers

MsgBox, % "Sum of all odd numbers from 49 to 4009 is " . funSumOfOddNumbers(49, 4009)
```

**Output**

```
Sum of all odd numbers from 49 to 4009 is 4019449
```